# Почему BeautifulSoup при парсинге выдает пустой список

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

Имеется код

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 

r =  requests.get('http://wm.exchanger.ru/asp/wmlist.asp')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
tb = soup.find_all('tr', class_='tooltip tooltipstered')
print(tb)
```

При запуске получаю вот такой ответ `[]`

Вот на скрине панель админки, показано что вроде как объекты имеются, не понимаю в чем проблема
[image: cr]

Comment: Значит, он не сразу получает все данные. Еще я не уверен, что запрос правильно формируется, я бы делал так: `soup.select('tr.tooltip.tooltipstered')`. Кст, попробуйте: `print([tr['title'] for tr in soup.select('.tooltip')])`

Comment: С запросом все верно, а вот про то что данных еще нет в этом @gil9red, прав. Выведите ваш  r.text, скорее всего там еще не будет тех данных которые вы запрашиваете. По тому что они подтягиваются Ajax'ом

Comment: @gil9red спасибо за ответ, помогло